# How to hide/display controls in ios using storyboards?

Tags: ios, xamarin, autolayout, storyboard

I'm using storyboards and autolayout in a Xamarin ios project, and I find that I want a UI to change depending on a user interaction. E.g. an option button should either display a login form OR a register form. All other views/controls should be the same but as a register form has more fields the space occupied might differ.

The above is just one example, and I find that I need this is several views and assume that there's a control or pattern that I should be using.

Comment: You want to operate the controls on storyboards instead of  in code ?

Comment: Please provide more details about your layout and the expected results. Do you want to switch between two forms or transform one to another? Now your intention is unclear.

Comment: Ok, the above example was an attempt at a less specific scenario to make the question more general, but I'll instead try my actual problem instead.  I have a view with 2 vertically stacked "containers"(views). The 2nd has a list of buttons for different options. The first container displays todays date and a button to an entry form _if not already entered_, otherwise instead of the button, todays values should be displayed. As @Duncan suggested below I could go with two different views but that would mean duplicating the 2nd containers buttons and logic.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about Xamarin, so I'll have to answer in terms of native iOS development and assume there's an equivalent.

It sounds like you want the same button to take the user to different storyboard scenes based on the current state.

That's easy. Instead of linking a segue directly to your button, create segues from your source scene to each destination scene and give them unique identifiers. Then hook the button to an `IBAction` method. In that method, check the relevant state, and use `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` to invoke the appropriate segue:

```
@IBAction func handleButton(_ sender: Any) {
   if userIsRegistered {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerSegue", sender: sender) 
   } else {
      performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: sender) 
   }
}
```

That's Swift code - you'll have to figure out the equivalent C# on your own, but it should at least give you the idea.

Comment: Actually, this is what I'm trying to avoid. In the above example, I can agree that having multiple views and navigating between them would be a fair solution, unless the view contained more info that would need to be implemented on both screens. I guess one way would be to implement the partial view as xib's and load them dynamically?